# Hibernate throwing StackOverflow Exception(Spring Boot)

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with SprinBoot/JPA in an integration via XML. I have to read an XML file and persist the data into my db. 
Steps:

- I must verify if this XML is not recurrent if it does, I have to update this register.
- Each XML comes with a list of items, I have to verify if each child already exists, if it does I have to update, if not I have to create a new one.
- I have to verify if some child is not recurrent and if it not, I have to remove this item.
- I have to verify if the material, color and product are existent otherwise I have to create a new one for each case.

Generally, everything works fine. But I have some cases when I getting a StackOverflow Exception.

- It's not because it is recursive because 90% of the files are saved correctly and updated correctly.
- I tried to save separately the children, no success.
- It's always the same files that throw the exception.
- It's not the memory because I have success cases that the file is bigger than the ones who failed.
- I can save the success files multiple times and no error occurs but If I try to save just one problematic error and the exception occurs.

This is my class responsible for managing the loaded XML and persisting

```
    @Override
    public void createProductionSet(ClientOrder clientOrder) throws Exception {
        try{
            List<Long> recurrent = new ArrayList<>();
            ProductionOrder order = orderService.findByCodeAndClientCode(clientOrder.getOp(), clientOrder.getClientCode());
            boolean newProdOrder = order == null,
                    hasChildrenInfo = hasChildrenInfo(clientOrder);

            if(newProdOrder)
                order = new ProductionOrder(clientOrder.getOp(), clientOrder.getClientCode(), clientOrder.getObservation());
            order.setItems(new ArrayList<>());
            if(hasChildrenInfo)
                manageCollectionChildrenValues(clientOrder, order, newProdOrder, recurrent);
            else
                manageCollection(clientOrder, order, newProdOrder,recurrent,
                                loadColor(clientOrder.getColorReference(), clientOrder.getColor()),
                                loadMaterial(clientOrder.getMaterialReference(), clientOrder.getMaterial()),
                                loadProduct(clientOrder.getProductReference(), clientOrder.getProduct(), clientOrder.getUnitOfMeasurement()));

            if(!newProdOrder)
                prodOrderItemService.deleteNotIn(recurrent, order.getId());
            orderService.save(order);
        } catch(StackOverflowError t) {
            throw  new Exception("Erro de StackOverflowError : "+clientOrder.toString());
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.warn("ERRO >> "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void manageCollection(ClientOrder clientOrder, ProductionOrder order, boolean newProdOrder, List<Long> recurrent,
                                  MaterialColor materialColor, Material material, Product product) {
        for(ItemOrder item : clientOrder.getItems()) {
            item.setColorObj(materialColor);
            item.setMaterialObj(material);
            item.setProductObj(product);
            manageItem(item, order, newProdOrder, recurrent);
        }
    }

    private void manageCollectionChildrenValues(ClientOrder clientOrder, ProductionOrder order, boolean newProdOrder, List<Long> recurrent) {
        for(ItemOrder item : clientOrder.getItems()) {
            item.setColorObj(loadColor(item.getColorReference(), item.getColor()));
            item.setMaterialObj(loadMaterial(item.getMaterialReference(), item.getMaterial()));
            item.setProductObj(loadProduct(item.getProductReference(), item.getProduct(), clientOrder.getUnitOfMeasurement()));
            manageItem(item, order, newProdOrder, recurrent);
        }
    }

    private void manageItem(ItemOrder item, ProductionOrder order, boolean newProdOrder, List<Long> recurrent) {
        ProdOrderItem aux = null;
        if(!newProdOrder)
            aux = prodOrderItemService.findOneByProductionOrderAndSize(order.getId(), item.getSize());

        if(aux != null) {
            aux.update(item);
            recurrent.add(aux.getId());
        }else {
            aux = new ProdOrderItem(item, order);
            order.getItems().add(aux);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasChildrenInfo(ClientOrder clientOrder) {
        return clientOrder.getColorReference() == null
                && clientOrder.getProductReference() == null
                && clientOrder.getMaterialReference() == null;
    }

    private Product loadProduct(String reference, String description, String unitOfMeasurement) {
        if(reference != null && !reference.isEmpty()) {
            Product product = productService.findProductByReference(reference);
            if (product != null)
                return product;
            return productService.save(new Product(description, reference, unitOfMeasurement));
        }
        return productService.loadFirstOrDefault();
    }

    private MaterialColor loadColor(String reference, String description) {
        if(reference != null && !reference.isEmpty()) {
            MaterialColor materialColor = colorService.findByReference(reference);
            if (materialColor != null)
                return materialColor;
            return colorService.save(new MaterialColor(reference, description));
        }
        return colorService.loadFirstOrDefault();
    }

    private Material loadMaterial(String reference, String description) {
        if(reference != null && !reference.isEmpty()) {
            Material material = materialService.findByReference(reference);
            if (material != null)
                return material;
            return materialService.save(new Material(description, reference, null));
        }
        return materialService.loadFirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

These are my models:

```
@Entity(name = "production_order")
public class ProductionOrder {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updated;

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private boolean deleted;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
private String code;

@Column(length = 30)
private String clientCode;

@Column(length = 200)
private String observation;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy ="productionOrder", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private List<ProdOrderItem> items;

...
```

}

```
@Entity(name = "order_item")
public class ProdOrderItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
private String size;

@Column(nullable = false)
private float quantity;

@Column(nullable = false)
private float weight;

@Column(nullable = false)
private float tolerance;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updated;

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private boolean deleted;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private Product product;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "color_id")
private MaterialColor color;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Material material;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "characteristic_id")
private Characteristic characteristic;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="order_id")
private ProductionOrder productionOrder;
```

And this is the log:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1929)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at
```

The complete log is [here, together with 2 xml files](https://github.com/Grimmjowjack/Error/blob/master/README.md#hibernate-throwing-stackoverflow-exceptionspring-boot)

Comment: Why do you think you need both `@OneToMany(cascade=ALL)` and `@Cascade(ALL)`?

Comment: My mistake. I have to remove the eager too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be in FetchType.EAGER try to remove it:

```
@Entity(name = "production_order")
public class ProductionOrder {
....
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="productionOrder", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private List<ProdOrderItem> items;
```

Comment: I tried. It was lazy before, the same thing happened.